# DIH Indexing duplicates document after Atomic Updates using Solr API

Tags: solr

I am using Solr 7.5.0 For Indexing using DIH.On First Time Indexing using DIH is working Properly

**DIH Request Format:**

Url:http://localhost:8983/solr/LatestDemo1/dataimport?command=full-import&Person=1,2,3&entity=Person&commit=true&clean=false

**Indexing data After DIH:**

```
{"response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"P1",
        "CreatedOnUtc":"2019-04-05T10:39:29.820Z",
        "Name":"Mahesh",
        "Age":25,
        "Gender":"M"
      }
}
```

After Performing partial Indexing using Atomic Updates,Its updating my fields like Name,LastName easily

**Update Using Atomic Updates Using Solr API**

Url: http://localhost:8983/solr/LatestDemo1/update?commit=true&clean=true

Method:Post

Data:

```
[
    {
     "id":"P1",
     "Name":{"set":"Rakesh"},
     "LastName":{"set":"Girase"},
    }
]
```

**Indexing data after Atomic Updates:**

```
{"response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"P1",
        "CreatedOnUtc":"2019-04-05T10:39:29.820Z",
        "Name":"Rakesh",
        "Age":25,
        "Gender":"M",
        "Lastname":"Girase"
      }
    ]  
}
```

That is completely working Fine But When I again Used DIH For Indexing  then documents gets duplicated like below

```
{"response":{"numFound":2,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "id":"P1",
        "CreatedOnUtc":"2019-04-05T10:39:29.820Z",
        "Name":"Mahesh",
        "Age":25,
        "Gender":"M"
      },
      {
        "id":"P1",
        "CreatedOnUtc":"2019-04-05T10:39:29.820Z",
        "Name":"Rakesh",
        "Age":25,
        "Gender":"M",
        "Lastname":"Girase"
     }
    ]
}
```

Here, I already declare my Id field as UniqueKey in managed schema as below

> `<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>`

It should not duplicate the document using DIH after Atomic updates using API

Any suggestions are appreciated..Thanks in advance.

Comment: check if your field named id has indexed=true in the schema.xml?

Comment: <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>

Yes,it is also true

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti what difference it makes when we have unique field indexed=true ?